# Update bower.json when running `bower update`

Tags: javascript, updates, bower, package-managers

Is it possible to update your bower.json file to the latest version after running `bower update`? Seems silly to have to go in & do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried "version": "latest" ?